# How to ensure accessibility for a variable-length collection of name fields in a form

Tags: website-design, forms, accessibility

My company supports a legacy application which uses a data form containing a Recipient section and a Sender section.  Each section, upon first load, contains three text inputs (horizontally aligned) with labels above them that read Last Name, First Name, and Organization.  There is a button which causes a new set of inputs to appear beneath the first; this allows the user to enter multiple names.

My question, what is the optimal combination of ARIA roles and labels to ensure accessibility and 508 compliance?  A user relying on assistive technology needs to be able to distinguish, for example, the "First Name" input in the Recipient section and the "First Name" input in the Sender section.  The former should have ARIA label "To First Name" and the latter should have ARIA label "From First Name".

Below is a sample of what one section of the form looks like with two records filled in.

| **Last Name** | **First Name** | **Organization** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jones | Robert | Sunnyside Corp. |
| Smith | Peter | ABC Co. |
| [button Add New] |  |  |

Comment: This leans towards an implementation question. Can you share the results of any screen reader tests so far and add the actual problem to the question?

Comment: @jazZRo Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "the actual problem".  I expressed my problem to the best of my abilities - I don't know how to ensure accessibility to the form in its current design.  In saying "this leans towards an implementation question" you are perhaps implying that the question is off-topic for this forum?  If that's the case, I'm sorry, can you suggest another forum that would be more appropriate?

Comment: With actual problem I mean; why wouldn't it already be accessible? Following standards and using the right semantic elements you should not need any extra role attributes. But if you know accessibility is an actual problem here, then what is that problem? If this is just a question about how to code it, then this is better asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I strongly suggest leaving role-related questions on UX StackExchange. If I’m not mistaken, this forum targets UI designers. And it’s within their responsibility to define UI elements’ exposed names and roles.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question: You should solve the issue with on of the [`section` roles](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#section).

A section carries an accessible name to divide contents. It makes sure the name of the section is announced when the user enters the section, leaves it, or asks for announcement of the current position.

It is not necessary to add the name of the section to each input field, the same as it is not necessary to add the name of the document to everything.

In forms, the most straight forward way to do this, is a *fieldset*, which is the standard form component to group inputs. Its role is [`group`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#group), which inherits from `section`.

#### Recipients

| **Last Name** | **First Name** | **Organization** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jones | Robert | Sunnyside Corp. |
| Smith | Peter | ABC Co. |
| [button Add New Recipient] |  |  |

When entering the section for the first time, focusing on the first input, NVDA would announce

> Recipients grouping, Last Name, input.